# Redux business logic best practice

Tags: reactjs, redux, frontend, logic, flux

Im building a shopping cart with React and Redux and failing to understand the best practice flow.

My Cart ACTIONS:

```
export const addToCart = (product) => (dispatch, getState) => {
  let { products: cartProducts } = getState().cart;
  let { newCartProducts, totalPrice } = handleAddToCart(cartProducts, product);
  dispatch(
    add({
      products: newCartProducts,
      total: totalPrice,
    })
  );
};
```

Mock-Server handlers: (All the logic of updating the product is going here => my main question is if this is makes any sense.

```
export function handleAddToCart(cartProducts, currentProduct) {
  let idx = cartProducts.findIndex((p) => p.id === currentProduct.id);
  let productInCart = cartProducts[idx];
  if (productInCart) {
    let updatedProduct = {
      ...currentProduct,
      quantity: productInCart.quantity + 1,
      price:
        productInCart.price +
        applySale({
          ...currentProduct,
          quantity: productInCart.quantity + 1,
          currentTotal: productInCart.price,
        }),
    };
    cartProducts.splice(idx, 1, updatedProduct);
  } else cartProducts.push({ ...currentProduct, quantity: 1 });
  let totalPrice = cartProducts.reduce((acc, val) => (acc += val.price), 0);
  return { newCartProducts: cartProducts, totalPrice };
}
```

Cart reducer:

```
};
export default (state = DEFAULT_STATE, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "ADD_TO_CART":
      return {
        products: [...action.payload.products],
        total: action.payload.total,
      };

    default:
      return DEFAULT_STATE;
  }
};
```

As you see from the code, I kept action and reducer logic to minimum and let the handler manipulate data. only after the data is manipulated, I insert it to the state.
After giving it thought, the reducer ADD_TO_CART is only symbolic because it gets an array and not an item so it can be actually a multi purpose reducer which is i think not so good.
Would be great to hear more opinions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We specifically recommend [putting as much logic as possible into reducers](https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide#put-as-much-logic-as-possible-in-reducers), and [treating actions as "events" that describe "what happened" with the minimal amount of data inside](https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide#model-actions-as-events-not-setters).

Also, note that you should be using [our official Redux Toolkit package](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-8-modern-redux), which will drastically simplify your Redux logic.

Comment: To add to this, `cartProducts.splice()` and `cartProducts.push()` are mutating the `state.cart.products` array.  Using the toolkit to handle the updating would avoid that sort of error.  I also think that it makes more sense to derive `total` from a selector but maybe that's just me.

Answer (score -1):

This is considered as an anti pattern in modern React ecosystem.

According to single responsibility principle
keep your business logic in a simple way with custom hooks (Use prototype inheritance in it, if required), To store API calls use Tanstack Query and to store global data use Jotai (Atoms). This libraries are very easy to learn and maintain.

You don't need to write Redux (action, reducers and store), Redux toolkit and other boilerplate codes today. Even you learn this concepts it was not so useful in other stacks.

Even today many React interviewers asks for Redux questions, I hope they will update their projects with the mentioned best practices soon.

A sample snippet is given below.

```
const Counter = () => {
  const {sendCounterdata} = useCounterAPI() // TanstackQuery
  const [counter, setCounter] = useAtom(counterAtom); // Jotai atom

 // Custom hook
  const { increment, decrement, submit } =
   useCounter({setCounter, onSubmit: sendCounterdata});

  return (
    <>
      {counter}
      <Button onPress={increment}>Increment</Button>
      <Button onPress={decrement}>Decrement</Button>
      <Button onPress={submit}>Submit</Button>
    </>
  );
};
```

NOTE: React team recommends to use Custom hooks over HOC for business logics.

Bonus: You can write the unit test for that custom hook 'useCounter' easily.